# How to hide navigation bar and its title on scroll and display it as largetitle only in ios UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uinavigationcontroller

How do I make the navigation bar disappear when the user scrolls down? Also, as the user scrolls down I want to prevent the title from showing in the middle of the navigation bar. I want it to show only on the left side of the navbar as a large title. I found a way to make the navbar disappear on scroll using the hidesBarsOnSwipe = true property. but how do I make the title disappear as well when scrolling down and up and only show the title as the large title on the left side of the screen as Instagram does?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share any code? Stackoverflow is not about letting others solve your task.